# low-quality post review ends in "No page found"

Tags: bug

While reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1859307 and selecting `recommend deletion` -> "This is commentary .. " -> [Delete] I get redirected to page

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15826454/recommend-delete?delete-main=1&fkey=a969ff351af3e60b7fca94074dd604e5

With a "Page not found" message. Same happened with https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1859153 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1859370

Happened multiple times on same question when retrying.

Seems the question does not go out of the queue.

Comment: Reproduced here. I click on "delete" and I get the "Page not found" message.

Comment: @SonerGönül It was happening over a 15+ minute time frame, just got it again. **Definitively** still there.

Comment: @hims056: Yes that is the same issue, sorry for the duplicate.